# `Cannot find name 'Array'` in Typescript Compiler pre-emit diagnostics

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm using the Typescript Compiler API to do some type-checking in a program I've written. This program is fairly large and includes imports that import other files, etc.

My issue is that, when I create the program using `ts.createProgram` and look at the pre-emit diagnostics, there are over 1000 entries of the error `Cannot find name 'Array'`. Additionally, I've noticed that when using certain Typescript features (like the `Exclude` utility type), even more errors show up in the pre-emit diagnostics. Interestingly, there are never any errors in `emitResult.diagnostics`

I'm not exactly sure how to provide a reproducible example, but here's the compiler host configuration I'm using. We use Typescript v4.x.x -- I'm not sure if that will affect what features we have available.

```
import ts from 'typescript';
import {readFileSync} from 'fs';

const defaultCompilerHost = ts.createCompilerHost({});

const customCompilerHost = function (filename, sourceFile) {
  return {
    getSourceFile: (name, languageVersion) => {
      if (name === filename) {
        return sourceFile;
      } else {
        return defaultCompilerHost.getSourceFile(name, languageVersion);
      }
    },
    writeFile: (filename, data) => {},
    getDefaultLibFileName: () => 'lib.d.ts',
    useCaseSensitiveFileNames: () => false,
    getCanonicalFileName: (filename) => filename,
    getCurrentDirectory: () => '',
    getNewLine: () => '\n',
    getDirectories: () => [],
    fileExists: () => true,
    readFile: () => '',
  };
};

const filename = 'file.ts';
const content = readFileSync(filename, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' });
console.log(content);
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(filename, content, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest);

const program = ts.createProgram([filename], {}, customCompilerHost(filename, sourceFile));
const emitResult = program.emit();
const checker = program.getTypeChecker();
```

Additionally, the TSConfig file is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src", "shared"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Interestingly, there are never any errors in `emitResult.diagnostics`

That will only include the emit diagnostics and not the type checking diagnostics.

> Additionally, the TSConfig file is

See the first argument to `ts.createCompilerHost`. You'll want to ensure that's based off the tsconfig.

> there are over 1000 entries of the error Cannot find name 'Array'

It's probably not finding the `lib.d.ts` file. You probably see the diagnostic for `File 'lib.d.ts' not found`. Try changing the code to provide the full path and share the compiler options amongst all the function calls:

```
getDefaultLibFileName: () => ts.getDefaultLibFilePath(compilerOptions),
```

Then implement `fileExists`, `readFile`, and `getDirectories`:

```
getDirectories: ts.sys.getDirectories,
fileExists: ts.sys.fileExists,
readFile: ts.sys.readFile,
```